# How to add `more text` to an error message?

Tags: expl3, compilation-error

For the mwe below, I was expecting:

> ERROR: Package foo Error: text bar more text baz

Instead:

> ERROR: Package foo Error: text bar

Why the discrepancy?

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{xparse}

    \ExplSyntaxOn

    \msg_new:nnnn{foo}{msg}{text~#1}{more~text~#2}

    \NewDocumentCommand{\Test}
    {}
    {
      \msg_error:nnnn{foo}{msg}{bar}{baz} 
    }

    \ExplSyntaxOff

    \begin{document}

    \Test

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'more text' argument is what is shown if the user presses `H` after the initial message is issued. As such, the first text tends to be something of the form

> LaTeX encountered an error due to XXXX.

and the 'more text' is of the form

> This might be caused by YYYY, you could try ZZZZ.

or

> LaTeX was asked to do YYYY, but that is not possible here because ZZZZ.

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile on the terminal *without* any option such as `-interaction=nonstopmode` or `-interaction=batchmode`. If I compile your document on the terminal with `pdflatex docu.tex`:

```
! Package foo Error: text bar

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.18 \Test

? h

more text baz

? 
(./docu.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on docu.log.
```

After the first `?` prompt, I've pressed `h` followed by Enter. This brought the `more text baz`. After the second `?` prompt, I've pressed Enter. This told TeX to continue.